# How to lock levels in Android app

Tags: android

I am developing a quiz application in Android. In my application I'm having categories and I added levels in each category. 
Now I need to lock all the categories except the first one. The user will be able to unlock the Categories only after he/she completes the specific goal of the level. I don't know how to lock categories in Android. Categories are in the form of buttons. By using the following I'm populating the list and passing of three categories, i.e. Hollywood, Bollywood and Music.

```
hollywood = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_hollywood);
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
            "Font/game_font.ttf");
    hollywood.setTypeface(tf);
    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            settings.edit().putBoolean("check", false).commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SceneActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    };
    hollywood.setOnClickListener(listener);


    bollywood = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_bollywood);
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
            "Font/game_font.ttf");
    bollywood.setTypeface(tf);
    listener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            settings.edit().putBoolean("check", false).commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SceneActivity1.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    };
    bollywood.setOnClickListener(listener);
    music = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_music);
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
            "Font/game_font.ttf");
    music.setTypeface(tf);
    listener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            settings.edit().putBoolean("check", false).commit();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SceneActivity2.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    };
    music.setOnClickListener(listener);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods to solve this

1. Use [shared preference](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fcontent%2FSharedPreferences.html&ei=XLZRVdHXE4ykuQSwuoCYBg&usg=AFQjCNFyaMlF7pqBKbWPbXr7H1Wg4gKaoA&sig2=LcGO2sUO0WKKpDVDTZpWqg&bvm=bv.92885102,d.c2E) in your application where you can handle the situation onlick
2. Use [sqlite](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fdatabase%2Fsqlite%2FSQLiteDatabase.html&ei=07ZRVZDnDcrGuASg0oBI&usg=AFQjCNGHrlZI8DewY8QwqR2vRa37N2GJpg&sig2=5mwjKtL4aMo_e-euIoixVA) database and update the column appropriately

Let me know if you need further information

For shared preference you can use [TinyDb](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo)

This class simplifies calls to SharedPreferences in a line of code. It can also do more like: saving a list of strings, integers and saving images. All in 1 line of code!

Example usage:

```
    TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(context);

    tinydb.putInt("clickCount", 2);
    tinydb.putFloat("xPoint", 3.6f);
     tinydb.putLong("userCount", 39832L);

    tinydb.putString("userName", "john");
    tinydb.putBoolean("isUserMale", true); 

    tinydb.putList("MyUsers", mUsersArray);
    tinydb.putImagePNG("DropBox/WorkImages", "MeAtlunch.png", lunchBitmap);
```

//These plus the corresponding get methods are all included
This is just an example of how easy it is to use. There are many more usefull methods included in the class. Enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you so much vinay. I m not familiar with those both.can you please help me out with the code for shared preferences....pls

Comment: Should i use sharepreference or tinydb?

Comment: I have already stored Values i just need to add condition for locking and unlocking levels